# With selenium on python don't know how to shut down a banner which is preventing selenium from accessing the page content

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to open a site with Selenium (with Python) using Chrome browser, but when I do, a full screen promo banner immediately pops-up and I can't access the site content unless I close it.
On the top right there is an "x" as if it was a quit button, but actually it's an element **::before**
and from its description it seems to me that it doesn't contain any button element.
If I operate manually, both clicking on the x and on the upper part of the page outside the banner, the latter closes, but I really don't understand how to access it with selenium.
The webpage I'm trying to open is https://sports.bwin.it/it/sports

Needless to say I'm quite inexperienced, so I hope this question won't sound too basic, but I wasn't able to find a solutione in the selenium docs or on the web; if someone could give me any hint I would appreciate it.

[This is a screenshot from the page I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNq7O.jpg)

[This is part of the html code from the web page; the element I am talking about is the one pointed by the arrow;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1lsH.jpg)

Comment: The banner doesn't load for me and the html looks incomplete.

Comment: It doesn't always load, I think it depends on the fact that one has already visited the site in the same session, but it will if I open the site through selenium. Which part of the html seems incomplete? Sorry I am still a newbie

Comment: I personally don't think the css is helpful, but I was referring to the html. IT feels like it's incomplete to get an idea of the banner.

Comment: perhaps either a way to surefire reproduce the banner, or a screen shot would also help.

Comment: and, as always, check to see if it's an iframe.

Comment: I posted a screenshot from the html. It seems to be outside of the iframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screen shot the xpath you want to use would be something like this:

```
//*[@data-id='dj_sports_c_ovl_br']//span
```

full code would be something like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-id='dj_sports_c_ovl_br']//span"))
)
element.click();
```

Comment: Thank you it works. If it's not too much of a bother, may I ask you how did you manage to identify the element?

Comment: I mean, of course I founnd it in the element now that you pointed at it, but how should I have understood that that bit was the clickable element?

Comment: Good question. You can alwasy check to see if a click event is attached to it